# Maven cannot pull jars from Mirros

Tags: maven, fuse

We have a central repository within intranet. I set mirror as follow. The issue is when I try to download a dependency that is not available in my local repository, the dependency cannot be downloaded completely. Only .lastUpdated file is downloaded in directory. I cannot figure out whey this weird thing happened. But it I comment the mirror setting, the dependency could be downloaded correctly. But I need some ourselves developed dependencies that are residing on central repository. That means I cannot bypass the central repository to search on internet. Does anyone come across this creepy issue?

```
    <mirror>
        <id>central-proxy</id>
        <name>Central Repo</name>
        <url>http://*.*.*.*.*/artifactory/repo</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: is your repo a **mirror** or a **proxy** of the central maven repo?

Comment: Yes, it is. My colleague can access that repo. And they don't have any problem at all. My setting is as same as them. But I cannot access it. No idea why?

Comment: did you try just to add your artifactory repo as additional repo and not as a mirror?